# C++: reference counter for objects

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, raii

I need a reference counter for an object not allocated on the heap.

I need it to implement a RAII mechanism on objects that cannot be easily copied and destructed:

```
class File
{
private:
    int fd;
public:
    File( const std::string &path ) ... // opening file
    destroy( );                         // actually closing file

    File( const File &f ) ...           // just copying the fd
    ~File( );                           // doing nothing
}
```

For a scenario like this a `std::shared_ptr` is usually used: the constructor and the destructor of the object whose pointer is shared are called only once.

In my case, however, I'd prefer avoiding allocating the object on the heap. I'd need a `shared_object` class that does a job similar to `std::shared_ptr`, so that my class' non-copy-constructor and `destroy` function (in the example above) are called only once.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: @NiklasB. the destructor needs to do some reference counting. `shared_ptr` already has all that logic built-in.

Comment: @R. Martinho: Thanks, just realized that too. A second glance at the code can never hurt (:

Comment: Where do you plan to maintain the reference count if not on the heap?

Comment: "RAII mechanism on objects that cannot be easily copied and destructed" You can't have RAII without a destructor. So you've already broken RAII. What's wrong with either forbidding copying explicitly and using proper RAII semantics in `File`?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I'm not sure, that's why I asked this question...

Comment: @NicolBolas: I need to copy instances of `File` and pass it around, I cannot avoid it. Am I forced to allocate `File` on the heap and pass `std::shared_ptr` around? I was looking for other ways...

Comment: @peoro If not on the heap, then it's on the stack and scope dictates the lifecycle.  If you can manage it via scope, then great.  Otherwise, put it on the heap and use shared_ptr...  Just my opinion...

Comment: What's wrong with passing pointers to your `File`

Comment: You're wasting your time and needlessly complicate simple things by trying to reinvent mechanisms already provided by language. Just use `shared_ptr<File>` and be done with it. Your `File` class, however, has broken logic: `destroy` must be exterminated and its functionality should be moved into destructor. destructor must close fd if it has been opened. Copying file descriptors is bad idea, because once something closes copied fd, everything will break. While copying, you should open file again, or use OS-specific functions to duplicate file handle. Or you could make copy-constructor private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have shared pointer behavior while allocating *nothing* in dynamic storage ("on the heap") you can look at [various smart pointer implementation strategies](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html).  In [Modern C++ Design](http://www.amazon.ca/Modern-Design-Generic-Programming-Patterns/dp/0201704315), the author discusses many of these strategies in the "Smart Pointers" chapter, which is [freely (and legally) available online](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25264).

The technique you will be interested in is *reference linking*.  Using this technique, the smart pointer objects are linked together in a bi-directional doubly linked list instead of pointing to a dynamically allocated reference counter.

---

All that being said, using a `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr` or their Boost variants will probably be much faster to write and easier to maintain.  If dynamic allocation and the reference count are ever a bottleneck (I doubt it will be, but then we can't generalize too hastily), you can always take time to use a custom reference linking version instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide your own deleter to a std::shared_ptr that will call your custom destroy function instead of delete.

```
class File
{
private:
    int fd;
public:
    static void destroyThis(File* f){f->destroy();}
    File( const std::string &path ) ... // opening file
    void destroy( );                         // actually closing file

    File( const File &f ) ...           // You probably don't need this anymore.
    ~File( );                           // doing nothing
};

File fileObj("path");
std::shared_ptr<File> pf(&fileObj,std::bind(&File::destroyThis,std::placeholders::_1));
std::shared_ptr<File> pf2(pf);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following architecture meets your requirements:

```
// pseudo-code
class File
{
private:
    int fd;
    File* prev;
    File* next;
public:
    File(const std::string &path) :
        fd(open(path)),
        prev(0),
        next(0)
    {}

    void destroy()
    {
        close(fd);
    }

    File( const File &f )
         fd(f.fd),
         prev(&f),
         next(f.next)
    {
         if (next)
             next->prev = this;

         f.next = this;
    }


    ~File()
    {
         if (prev)
            prev->next = next;

         if (next)
            next->prev = prev;

         if ((!prev) && (!next))
            destroy();
    }
};
```

A doubly linked-list is maintained between duplicate File instances.  The last member of the list, and hence the last duplicate calls destroy.  No heap allocation required.

(Obviously this isn't thread safe.  You can protect with a mutex, or you can use lock-free methods for maintaining the list.)

Comment: Missing `operator=`, modifying members in `const` object in copy constructor, etc.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Thanks, not intended to be a finished product.  Just a quick scribble to convey the architecture.  const_cast can be used to modify next and prev, and operator= implementation is straightforward.

Comment: The more idiomatic way is to declare the `next` and `prev` members as `mutable` rather than use `const_cast<>()`, but my point was just that you should mention the fact that it's incomplete in the post.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Yes mutable works too ofc.  Ok done, I call it an architecture and label it pseudo-code.